# unable to boot from hard drive after upgrade to 12.04. error: symbol 'grub_xpuls' not found

Tags: installation, 12.04, grub2, re-installation

I just upgraded from Lucid to 12.04, and now I can't boot from my hard drive, but get the following error message:

the symbol 'grub-xpuls' not found

...and then it wants me to do something to grub rescue, and me being no expert, I have no idea what that might be.

Help please? I wish I could be more specific and less of a noob, but sadly...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just re-install grub or get grub-update. JUst try a live CD and go to terminal and eneter following to update grub:

```
Mount the partition containing your Linux: mount $partition /mnt/sda2
Reinstall grub: grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/sda2 $device
Backup the Grub: cd /boot/grub ; cp grub.cfg grub.cfg#1 ; cp menu.lst menu.lst#1 //if it's not the live cd boot directory
Update the grub: sudo update-grub
```

and you are done.

Comment: Okay, second problem: I can't be sudo. I'm currently a guest on my own computer, because it won't accept my password. It doesn't say it's wrong, which it does when I put something that isn't my password, it simply ignores me and asks again.

Comment: You are geust on the OS you installed previously. Now, try live Cd and you will be enter as root. Just try sudo from there.

Comment: I'm on a netbook, booting from a usb drive. Does that make a difference? Cause it doesn't work. Sorry, I feel like a complete idiot right now.